# Form.ProcessDialogKey seems to give ambigious keys pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0, key

Currently, I'm overriding the [`Form.ProcessDialogKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processdialogkey.aspx) inside my WinForms form to allow the user to directly select a tab page of a tab control inside the form when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> ... <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

I.e. pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> should select the first tab, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> the second tab, etc.

This is an excerpt of my code:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if ((e.KeyData & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
    {
       if ((e.KeyData & Keys.D1) == Keys.D1) tabIndex = 0;
       else if ((e.KeyData & Keys.D1) == Keys.D1) tabIndex = 0;
       else if ((e.KeyData & Keys.D2) == Keys.D2) tabIndex = 1;
       else if ((e.KeyData & Keys.D3) == Keys.D3) tabIndex = 2;
       // ...
    }
}
```

I discovered that my check give redundant results. E.g. when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>,

```
(e.KeyData & Keys.D3) == Keys.D3 // <<== TRUE.
```

is `true`, but also other checks are `true`, e.g.:

```
(e.KeyData & Keys.D1) == Keys.D1 // <<== also TRUE.
(e.KeyData & Keys.D0) == Keys.D0 // <<== also TRUE.
```

I do think this is quite logical, since the [`Keys` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) does lot of bitwise combination of other `Keys` member values.

So I do unsertand why I get too much `true` results, I just do not know how to do a correct check.

**My question:**

Can I use the `Form.ProcessDialogKey` method at all to check for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> combination or should I choose another aproach?

(If there is another aproach, I would love to get a link to it)

**Update 1:**

It seems that if I revers the check order, i.e. first `Keys.D9` and then down to `Keys.D1` that the matching works better (correct?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the & operator here is not correct.  The Keys enumeration has the [Flags] attribute but it is a combination of flags and a value.  Necessarily so, there are many more keys than bits in an int or long.  Some bits indicate a modifier, like Keys.Alt, but the lower 16 bits are the key code and you need to use the == operator to compare it.

Consider this code to keep it DRY:

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData >= (Keys.Alt | Keys.D1) && keyData <= (Keys.Alt | Keys.D9)) {
            int cmd = (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) - Keys.D0;
            // etc...
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Hans. After your answer, I tried to google for some documentation on how to correctly query for values inside a `Keys` variable for other cases like mine here. I found none. Could you kindly reveal some of your sources (URLs?).